# UI artifacts in unity editor 2021.1.1.19f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

After switching Unity Editor version from 2020.3.11f1 to 2021.1.1.19f1, the icons at the top of the screen appear weird, and text on them is unreadable.

[image: Top bar of buttons has severe color artifacting and borders]

I've tried to uninstall Unity and manually deleting Unity related files, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Unity 2021.1.X broke List rendering for me, so this wouldn't surprise me.